# Evaluate $n$th derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives

Is there some algorithm that is useful for finding the $n$th derivative of a function without the need to recognize the pattern?

Comment: No. (I must write more characters for comment to be added...)

Comment: There's the generalized Leibniz rule for products.

Comment: For simpler things like $\frac1x$, this isn't hard. (Actually, you can do it for any rational function — just do partial fractions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use efficient algorithms to compute series expansions and extract the desired derivatives that way, as pointed out in Bolzweir's answer. An efficient algorithm to compute series expansions is based on Newton-Raphson division for polynomials (see below), and then term by term integration which allows you to  compute the logarithm of series expansions. Here the number of correct term is doubled each iteration. To compute the exponential of a given series expansion, you can use the Newton-Raphson method to solve for the unknown series expansion by taking logarithms and using the algorithm for the logarithm. While this sounds complicated, the number of correct terms will still increase exponentially as a function of the number of steps.

Then this is sufficient to efficiently compute the series expansion of any given elementary function, as they can always be written in terms of logarithms and exponentials.

**Newton-Raphson division**

To find the reciprocal of a number y, you can consider the nonlinear equation:

$$1/x - y = 0$$

Newton's method then yields the successive approximations:

$$x_{n+1} = 2 x_n - y x_n^2$$

There are no divisions in this recursion, so this is a good method to compute the reciprocal of $y$. For polynomials, this algorithm works just as well. For given $P(x)$ we can compute $Q(x) = \frac{1}{P(x)}$ by putting $Q_0(x)=\frac{1}{P(0)}$ and evaluating:

$$Q_{n+1}(x) = 2 Q_n(x) - P(x) Q_n(x)^2$$

And here you only keep the first $2^n$ correct number of terms in $Q_n(x)$.

The series expansion of $\log\left[P(x)\right]$ is then obtained by trivial term by term integration of $Q(x)$.

Comment: He didn't ask about the series expansion…?